# plt-scheme : catching mouse click event on canvas

Tags: project, variable-assignment, racket

I am writing a tic-tac-toe game in plt-scheme as my AI course project.
The idea for gui is a grid with 9 boxes, each with a canvas, using panes ...
When the user click on a canvas, 'X' or 'O' will be drawn accordingly ...

The question is how can I catch mouse click event on canvas?
I found out I need to use on-event, but still don't know how?
Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I got it ...

```
(define canvas-box%
  (class canvas%
    (define/override (on-event e)
           (when (equal? (send e get-event-type) 'left-down) (foobar-callback)))
    (super-new)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got all mouse and keypad command for uses anywhere 
 here.

```
(define my-canvas%

(class canvas%
  (define/override (on-event event)
    (and 
        (send test reader (list (number->string (send event get-x))
                     (number->string (send event get-y)) ))
        (send test reader (list (send event get-event-type)))))
(define/override (on-char event)
  (define pressed (send event get-key-code))
   (if (char? pressed) (send test reader (list (make-string 1 pressed))) '()))  
  (super-new)))

(define tester%
 (class object%
  (super-new)
  (define command '())

  (define/public (reader x)
    (and (set! command x)
         (display x))
   )
  (define/public (outer)
    command)
  ))
```